# Environmental variable value showing in dist/main.js

Tags: webpack, dotenv

I'm working on a project using GPT3 and my apikey is showing in dist/main.js despite being a .env variable.

Here's the code where I'm referencing the variable

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

webpack config:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
      new Dotenv({systemvars: true}),

    // Add your plugins here
    // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
  ],
```

[and an image of how it looks in the main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFQ2R.png)

I tried using EnvironmentPlugin, DefinePlugin and using dotenv in stead of dotenv-webpack and the results were the same

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen. That's how the plug-in works. You don't have access to `process.env` in the browser - it's a Node API and your code cannot access either your server's env vars or anything your users have set locally. This is _build time_ configuration (vs. e.g. runtime, see [my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html)).

Comment: I see, I'll just make a server for it then